# How to make VS 2003 builds on Windows Server 2003 code sourced from TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, biztalk, tfsbuild, visual-studio-2003

I have a BizTalk 2004 solution that currently builds on Windows Server 2003 R2.
We recently moved to a new TFS 2012 server and I cannot find any information on how to set up a build agent for this configuration.

Our new build server is Windows Server 2008 R2 - and we cannot install BizTalk 2004 on it as BizTalk 2004 requires a database version that cannot be installed on 2008R2 so I cannot move it off the old Server 2003 R2 build machine..  We are beginning a very long process of converting the BizTalk app to BizTalk 2013 but that won't be finished for months...

I found someone reply months ago somewhere that you could use a 2010 build service on 2003 R2 and that it could be run/built from TFS 2012 - but there was no more info than this comment.

Can someone provide some information / links / suggestions on how to do this?: 
How to get a build agent or service installed/setup on Windows Server 2003 R2 to build a VS 2003 BizTalk solution sourcing files from TFS 2012; and build it via a VS 2012 build script?

Thank you!
Todd

Answer (score 2):

If you're up for any suggestion, I would say don't bother.

Even if the new BizTalk 2013 R2 based app takes a "few months", that's still barely consequential compared to the 10+ years you've had BizTalk Server 2004.

I think the effort to update the BizTalk Server 2004 build kit is better spent on the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, you can use TFS 2010 Build Controller and Build Agents with TFS 2012 (and 2013) server (I think you might need at least 2012 Update 2).
http://nakedalm.com/visual-studio-2012-update-2-supports-2010-build-servers/

TFS 2010 Build Controller/Agents do support Windows Server 2003 as you said:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578592(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I needed.  I'm not up on 2010 agents - I don't suppose you have any info on configuring 2010 agents to build 2003 projects?  I suppose I will find it but thought I'd ask...

Comment: Busy morning - just hit me - since it currently builds via VS 2010, It should just be a matter of connecting the two. Appreciate the help!

Comment: (I need more than 5 minutes to edit my comments... LOL) So - next:
Removing the old TFS server and being able to source code from the new TFS server is the primary goal. 
A quick glance and I didn't see any mention of build scripts  - so am I correct in I just upgrade the script as I did for other 2010 apps to run in TFS 2012, sourcing from the new 2012 TFS, with the difference being using a new build service on 2003 R2 instead of the old TFS machine build service.